# grpc request is taking time grom grpc queue to service level. how can we resolve it?

Tags: grpc, netty, grpc-java

grpc threads halts processing before the start of execution in high load scenario in spring gprc service.

response = obj1.execute(request).toBlocking().first();

As our processing time is less but request recieved and emitting is taking time.
we increased the netty server thread count but still there is no resolution.

Comment: Can you add some code snippets for your server side code since it's not clear what the problem is. Also you can add some log statements and see where things are getting stuck.